Angle bisector, median, perpendicular bisector concurrence problem
I'm encountering issues with the following problem (PUMaC problem B7 on geometry):
Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be a triangle such that the angle bisector of $\angle{BAC}$, the median from $B$ to side $AC$, and the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ intersect at a single point $X$. If $AX = 5$ and $AC = 12$, compute $BC^2$
.
Here is a crude diagram below:

Here is my incorrect solution:
Let $F$ be the midpoint of $AB$ and $D$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Since $FX$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, $AX=BX = 5$. And, $XD = \frac{1}2 BX = \frac{5}2$. Also, $AD = \frac{1}2 AC = 6$. Then by law of cosines
$$ \cos(\angle XAD) = \frac{5^2 + 6^2 - \frac{25}{4}}{2 \cdot 5 \cdot6 } = \frac{73}{80}$$
Since $\angle XAD = \angle XAB$,
$$ AF = AX \cos(\angle XAB) = \frac{73}{16} \implies AB = 2AF = \frac{73}{8} $$
By Apollonius's theorem, the length of the median $BD$ is given by
$$ BD^2 = \frac{2AB^2 + 2BC^2 - AC^2}{4} \implies BC^2 = 2BD^2 - AB^2 + \frac{1}2 AC^2 = 2 \cdot \left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{73}8\right)^2 + \frac{12^2}{2} = \boxed{\frac{6479}{64}} $$
However, the true answer is apparently $\frac{711}4$. Where is my mistake?

For a solution verification (tag added), please " identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.".

Why is $XD =\frac{1}{2} BX$?
Since $BD$ is the median, this is only true if $X$ is the centroid. It's not immediately apparent to me why that's the case.
